# How would I be able to split an audio file into multiple wav files using timpooints from an array or csv?

Tags: python, audio, split, output, segment

I made the following Python code that allows me to segment an audiofile (.wav) into smaller a segment by using timepoints from an array. However, I want to create multiple segments from the same audio file. Each row on my array has the start and stop points for a different segment. How would I be able to create multiple segmented wav files and name them each based on which row they are from?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

SegmentStart = seglimits[0,0] * 1000 
SegmentStop = seglimits[0,1] * 1000
SegmentedSong = AudioSegment.from_wav('/Test/sound1.wav')
SegmentedSong = SegmentedSong[SegmentStart:SegmentStop]
SegmentedSong.export('/Test/Segmented/newSong5.wav', format="wav")
```

the array looks like this [.34, .56], [.78,.86], [1.23, 1.78]

Comment: if you are familiar with constructing 2 dimensional arrays where one dimension you increment for each row of your input cvs file ... and other dimension holds a list similar to what you have shown of pairs of [start,end] timepoints ... then after reading in cvs file and populating above 2D array then next portion of your script you  iterate across this 2D array with outer loop being where you increment your row counter and inner loop where you walk through each timepoint pairs ... inside this inner loop you just cut the audio using your start and end timepoints and write audio to a file

Comment: alternative would be to read your csv file one row at a time ... on the current row read in its timepoint pairs ... for each pair perform your audio split and write output audio to labeled file  ... before doing this you must master ability to pluck the section of audio delimited by a timepoint pair

Comment: yet another approach would be to read in your audio file and populate an audio buffer ... be aware of the audio sample rate and its bit depth and number of channels (stereo or mono)   then master ability to pluck a snippet of audio from some arbitrary start timepoint until its end timepoint and dump that snippet into an output audio file

Comment: keep in mind you can always use your python to print out formatted text file which contains legal syntactically correct format to make ffmpeg command line calls to perform all your audio cutting ... here is proper syntax to cut the input audio file into a snippet with a defined start point and duration ...  ffmpeg -i $input_audio -ss $curr_window_start_seconds  -t $snip_duration -acodec copy ${curr_output_file}   ... ffmpeg handles floating point values for the starting point  (  -ss )  and duration parm (  -t  )

Comment: @ScottStensland Could you please show me how to do your first two suggestions? I am not sure how to do either of those. Thank you!!

Comment: I suggest you invest time to think and create code which achieves little steps ... writing software is all about looking at a problem and breaking it into solvable working nuggets ... one approach is to start from the inner most elemental deliverable and getting that working then layer atop the next  ... always having your code compile and execute ...  if I just gave you some solution you would not learn .. learning happens through trial and error ... put on your explorer hat and hunker down and prepare for frustration yet know it can be solved .. most critical of all is boat loads of practice